# Does smoothing make any sense for Bernoulli Naive Bayes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I'm trying to understand how the hyperparameters for the Bernoulli Naive Bayes in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html) work for doing Randomized Search CV.

If I use smoothing, and set `alpha = 0.1`, each feature will have its value increased by `0.1`. If I then set `binarize = 0.1`, would that mean that every single value will be set to 1?

Wouldn't that make alpha completely redundant since I can just fiddle with the binarize value instead?